# How to work with 3DM file

Tags: opengl, rhino3d

I have 3DM file which I was able to open in Rhino3D / Rhinoceros software. With this 3DM file I want to develop a model such as,

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/product/lebron-x-ps-elite-id-basketball-shoe/?piid=31819&pbid=933486182#

where I can change the color of different parts of image.

Is this possible using 3DM file? Can you explain, how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The 3DM file format can represent 3D NURBS and polygon mesh geometry, and can be read and written by the openNURBS toolkit: http://www.opennurbs.org.

While the example on the Nike web site looks 3D, it appears to me to just be a set of 2D rendered images that can be swapped out as the user customizes the shoe.

You could render each piece from within Rhino, and then build a web application to allow the user to customize, if you wanted to copy the model that Nike used.

Developing a professional web application to customize content like Nike did is not something that can be written down in a simple answer to your question.